# wrong order by date in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I get a list of objects like this

```
return Post.objects.filter(categoria=categoria)
```

And I send that to a template. I display them in the template like this

```
{% for p in posts reversed %}
```

That way I get the new posts on top. It works like that 99% of the time but it fails randomly were it will show the last post below some older post. The dates are correct, the last post shows that it has the most recent date yet it appears below some other older post.

Nothing special is done when it fails, I'm thinking it might be some obscure django bug.

Any ideas about what could be causing this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to avoid having to use `.order_by(...)` each time you query your model, use the `ordering` `Meta` option:

```
class Post(Model):
    # your fields here
    the_date = DateTimeField(...)

    class Meta:
        # sort by "the date" in descending order unless
        # overridden in the query with order_by()
        ordering = ['-the_date']
```

Answer (score 0):

Including an order_by when getting the objects seem to fix the problem.

Comment: I'm not very surprised that ordering fixed your ordering problem? :)

Comment: It still makes no sense to me that it fails without it.

Comment: Without an explicit ordering, either in the query or in the model definition, the `Post` objects will come out in whatever order the database returns them, which is generally undefined, unless your database explicitly returns query rows in a certain order. Thus, you should always use an explicit `ordering` or `order_by(...)` if the order matters.

Comment: I should note that the `reversed` iteration simply iterates the results in the reverse order that they were returned by the database. It doesn't know what order you want (unless you explicitly specify it, see my previous comment), or anything about your model.

Comment: By default, it would be sorted by ID.

Comment: still the newest post, that has the newest date, should have the newest id, placing it on top, but it failed sometimes. I still think it could be some bug that fails in certain conditions.